# Update query with variable

Tags: sql, string, oracle, sql-update

Is it possible to update a variable with a concatenation of variables(columns of VARCHARS2)?

```
UPDATE ARTICLE 
SET DESCRIPTION = (CPV_DESCRIPTION + '/' LEVEL1_DESCRIPTION + LEVEL2_DESCRIPTION+LEVEL3_DESCRIPTION) 
WHERE ID_ARTICULO = 209;

UPDATE ARTICLE 
SET DESCRIPTION = concat(CPV_DESCRIPTION,'/',LEVEL1_DESCRIPTION,' ',LEVEL2_DESCRIPTION' 'LEVEL3_DESCRIPTION) 
WHERE ID_ARTICULO = 209;
```

Both cases it gives me an error.

Comment: Specify the error!

Comment: The [string concatenation operator  in SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/operators003.htm#SQLRF51158) is `||` not `+` (+ is for numbers)  and [Oracle's `concat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions040.htm#SQLRF00619) function only accepts two parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @a_horse... concat() function only takes 2 parameters. When you specify more that 2 parameters to be concated, you need to use `||` operator. Also `+` is a logical operator in `Oracle` unlike its used in Java for concatenation.  Try this:

```
UPDATE ARTICLE
SET DESCRIPTION = CPV_DESCRIPTION
                  || '/'
                  ||LEVEL1_DESCRIPTION
                  ||' '
                  ||LEVEL2_DESCRIPTION
                  ||' '
                  ||LEVEL3_DESCRIPTION
WHERE ID_ARTICULO = 209;
```